# jQuery 'resize' not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, resize

Need some help.  I am using jQuery in combination with media queries for some responsive aspects of my header.  My client wants the header to be responsive to both devices and manual resize of the window.  Therefore, I have set all of my responsive functions in both single functions and then set those same functions wrapped inside of a $(window).on('resize', function).  Thanks to another poster on here, I was given the tip to wrap my responsive functions inside of a variable and then pass that variable to the resize function instead of rewriting it all out.  This was a great tip and a great thing for me to learn as an intermediate javascript writer.  However when I do this, the code does not work within the resize function.  If I type it all out exactly the same, it works fine.  But if I pass the function it does not work.  Can someone please help?  Code below:

```
                var win = $(window);
            var mainNav = $('.main-nav');
            var navItem = $('.main-nav li');
            var overlay = $('.nav-overlay');
            var header = $('#header');
            var subNav = $('.main-nav ul ul');
            var overlayIsVisible = false;
            var subNavIsVisible = false;
            var exitMain = $('.exit-main');
            var topNav = $('.top-nav');
            var hamburger = $('.tablet-buttons .hamburger');
            var exit = $('.tablet-buttons .exit');

                if ( header.is('*') ) {

                    navItem.hover(function() {
                        overlay.fadeIn('slow');
                        $(this).find('ul').toggleClass("active");
                        overlayIsVisible = true;
                    });

                    exitMain.click(function() {
                        overlay.fadeOut('fast');
                        overlayIsVisible = false;
                    });

                    function tabletNav() {

                        if (win.width() <= 1024) {

                            topNav.prependTo(overlay);
                            hamburger.click(function() {
                                overlay.fadeIn('slow');
                                hamburger.css('display', 'none');
                                exit.fadeIn('slow');
                            });
                            exit.click(function(){
                                overlay.fadeOut('slow');
                                exit.css('display', 'none');
                                hamburger.fadeIn('slow');
                            });
                        }
                        else{
                            topNav.insertAfter('.logo');
                        }
                    };

                    /*This makes the above Mobile/Tablet functions also work on resize of window*/

                    win.on('resize', tabletNav());

                };
```

Comment: You need to pass function reference to resize event, not calling it, so use: `win.on('resize', tabletNav);`. `win.on('load resize', tabletNav);`  to call it on page load too.FYI, you shouldn't check for windows width but instead use `window.matchMedia`, this is better to fit media queries (regarding cross browser support and scrollbar beeing part of viewport or not), see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia  Polyfill: https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/  CanIUse: http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia

Comment: Awesome, works perfect.  Thanks a ton and also thanks for the tip on matchMedia.